# How to put text on top in RadioButton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to achieve effect shown in attached file but without success. It is even possible? I was trying to put textbox inside the radiobutton and set to it horizontal and vertical content aligment but it's not working as I want.
Any advices are welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Resource**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RadioButton" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="Black" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="SemiBold" Margin="0,0,0,2" />
                        <BulletDecorator Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent" >
                            <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                <Grid Width="14" Height="14" >
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="Border" Fill="Transparent" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" />
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark" Margin="4" Fill="Black"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        </BulletDecorator>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Fill" Value="LightGray" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Fill" Value="White" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="4" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Xaml**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <RadioButton Content="1" Style="{StaticResource RadioButton}" Margin="5"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Content="2" Style="{StaticResource RadioButton}" Margin="5"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Content="3" Style="{StaticResource RadioButton}" Margin="5"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Content="4" Style="{StaticResource RadioButton}" Margin="5" ></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Content="5" Style="{StaticResource RadioButton}" Margin="5"></RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

**Result**

[image]