# Apply style to radio button

Tags: c#, winforms

my question may seem stupid, but I really couldn't find an answer for it. I'm trying to put text on top of a radiobutton instead of on the side. I have found this question [How to put text on top in RadioButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652027/how-to-put-text-on-top-in-radiobutton) which seems to answer my question, but how do I apply this to my radio buttons in my windows form. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and i'm working in a windows form application.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the link you shared is wpf, you cannot use that solution :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I'm pretty new to all of this stuff and there was just to much information to find what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WinForms, there are two properties:

```
radioButton1.CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
radioButton1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
```

Comment: You could still add AutoSize to false ;)

Comment: Thanks! Worked out perfectly!