# How to make radiobuttonbar in wpf xaml with a nice look

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, radio-button

I want for my user that they can select one option from a ItemsControl
When i use radiobuttons it is not looking nice so i like to have something like picture 2
but then with a nice solution to see what option is selected.

I am new to wpf, can someone point me to the right direction with xaml
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35060859/1506454

Comment: [A variant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24652027/1997232) to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Hey use a ListView and Binding the SelectedIndex do an Integer so you know which one is selected. In this way you could set a picture or some style properties in dependency to the SelectedIndex.
If you really want your solution than change the Back- or Foreground Property with an OnMouseUp or with a Command. Hope this helps